# hide values in a combo box if it's already selected in previous record on a contins form

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Sorry Andre your right I have edited my question.

I have a subform called frmIntContPhasesubform which has a field called Regimen, and it's row source is a table called lookupRegimen which has names of around 15 pills and the names themselves are the Primary Keys. Each patient gets a combination of five pills and when a patient is prescribed a pill I do not want that same name to show up in the next combo field choice for that patient in that subform. I have attached a picture of the form. What do you think will be a good solution for it? !

Comment: I have edited my question kindly check and give me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the combobox's entries are drawn from a table or query, you can simply exclude values already selected before with a "WHERE x NOT IN ()" statement. Also assuming pills prescribed must be limited for each date.

tbl_Patient_Medication (would be the table linking 1 Patient with the desired Pill with fields Patient_ID_FK and Pill_Name_FK)
tbl_Pills (would contain information to the pills with field Pill_Name)

Name textboxes for patient and date as tbxPatient and tbxDate then combobox RowSource query could look like this:

```
SELECT Pill_Name
FROM tbl_Pills
WHERE Pill_Name Not In 
        (SELECT Pill_Name_FK FROM tbl_Patient_Medication 
        WHERE Patient_ID=[tbxPatient] AND pDate=[tbxDate]);
```

To work properly, add the following GotFocus event to the combobox (named cboPill):

```
Private Sub cboPill_GotFocus()
Me.cboPill.Requery
Me.Recalc
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited my question kindly check and give me a solution. Thanks

Comment: This answer is an appropriate solution. If you still have difficulty then edit question with examples of data to show table structure (as text, not image).

Comment: I want the records to remain on the subform till I close the form.  Right now when I select a value in the combo box it immediately saves and starts a new record. Although the values get subtracted from the list in the combo box but am not able to get the values back if I want to prescribe them to a new patient or for different date. It seems as if the values get deleted in the record source of the combo box or may be the where criteria in the query seems to be not working. I have also attached a picture of the data structure.